# coffeescript promise chaining with function definition

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, q

When do promise chaining in coffeescript, function defined for then need to bind to 'this'.

```
  $q.fcall somecall
  .then ((url)->
    dosomething()
    ).bind(this)
  .catch (err)->
    console.log 'error occured', err
```

However, the above compiles into following,which is wrong. How to write correctly then ? Or is there a way for coffeescript to represent this ?

```
  $q.fcall(somecall).then(((function(url) {
    dosomething()
  }).bind(this))["catch"](function(err) {
    return console.log('error occured', err);
  })));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`=>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) instead of binding it yourself, it will read much easier and be correct.

```
$q.fcall somecall
.then (url) =>
  dosomething()    
.catch (err)->
  console.log 'error occured', err
```

However, that doesn't really make sense as you don't refer to `this` in your function. You might want to actually just pass `dosomething` directly to `then()`, so its `ThisBinding` is preserved.

Comment: It does help. but after compilation, the generated javascript code still shows `["catch"](function(err) {
    return console.log('error is', err);
  }));`

Comment: @WeideZhang: What's wrong with that? `o.m()` and `o['m']()` are equivalent and [`catch` is a keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) so CoffeeScript is using the string form.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you can use anonymous functions doesn't mean you have to. Giving your callbacks names often leads to clearer code:

```
some_descriptive_name = (url) ->
  dosomething()
the_error = (err) ->
  console.log 'error occurred', err

$q.fcall somecall
  .then some_descriptive_name.bind(@)
  .catch the_error
```

Or:

```
some_descriptive_name = (url) => # fat-arrow instead of bind
  dosomething()
the_error = (err) ->
  console.log 'error occurred', err

$q.fcall somecall
  .then some_descriptive_name
  .catch the_error
```

If your functions are just one-liners then anonymous functions are fine but if they're longer, it is very easy to get lost in CoffeeScript's whitespace.